# Can not install Airflow Snowflake provider package on Google Cloud Composer

Tags: sqlalchemy, airflow, pypi, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake on a Google Cloud Composer environment.

apache-airflow-providers-snowflake has a requirement sqlalchemy >= 1.4.0

However,apache-airflow 2.2.5+composer has requirement sqlalchemy <1.4.0,>=1.3.18.
Specifically the version Composer has of sqlalchemy is 1.3.24.

I have tried upgrading sqlalchemy package but got conflicting dependencies.

I have tried the other versions of airflow on composer and had same conflicting dependencies as well.

Does that mean as of now, there is no way to work with apache-airflow-providers-snowflake on Google Cloud Composer ??

Attached screenshot of the error I get
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I35HG.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the answer by Daniel T , I manually installed snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.5 as a PyPi package, and then installed apache-airflow-providers-snowflake

However, I got broken DAGs due to "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.sql.roles'".
This is caused by a known [issue](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/234) while using sqlalchemy==1.2.5 with airflow.

Another [issue](https://github.com/tokern/data-lineage/issues/85) suggested downgrading to 1.2.4 which helped resolve all my errors.

***So the final solution is to manually install snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.4 as a PyPi package, and then install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake.***

Answer (score 1):

This is raised as a bug on Cloud Composer [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229759204).

A suggestion on that thread is:

> you can manually install snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.5 as a PyPi package, and then install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake.

The hard requirement comes from `snowflake-sqlalchemy` which you can see [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/blob/main/setup.cfg#L56).

`1.2.5` was the last version to not have a minimum sqlalchemy of `>=1.4.0` which you can see [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/blob/v1.2.5/setup.py#L37)

It's safe (if this is the only provider you have installed to depend on snowflake-sqlalchemy) to install `snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.5` as the provider [requires](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/index.html) `>=1.1.0`

Comment: I installed snoqflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.5 and this allowed me to install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake indeed.

However this caused me to be thrown a new error : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.sql.roles'"

I searched for a while and it appears the problem is with snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.5
https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/234